# Javascript - initializing variables?

Tags: javascript, constructor

In the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7fh0x901/1/ I am getting undefined while invoking show method. What's wrong?

What am i looking for - Trying to initialize name and age when the object is called.

```
function a(name, age) {
this.name;
this.age;    
(function x() {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age
    alert(this.name+" <<inside self invoking>> "+this.age);
})();
this.show = function() { alert(this.name+" <<show>> "+this.age); }
}

var a1 = new a("rahul", 24);
a1.show();
```

Comment: You haven't initialized this.name & this.age in function a()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new scope in the inner function x so "this" is not like the previous "this". Maybe what you want to define is something like

```
function a(name, age) {
  this.name;
  this.age; 
  var that = this;
    (function x() {
        that.name = name;
        that.age = age
        alert(that.name+" <<inside self invoking>> "+that.age);
    })();
    this.show = function() { alert(this.name+" <<show>> "+this.age); }
}

var a1 = new a("rahul", 24);
a1.show();
```

I think you are looking for this.

Comment: What's the point of the `x()` function.  It isn't needed at all.

Comment: Well, it is not needed, but if I think he is looking for an example to show him the scopes in javascript. Something illustrative to learn how the scopes work

Comment: @ReikVal Well said..There is surely no need of x() function... jfriend00..You better clarify with the user who asked this and his requirement...no good in votedown each ones answer

Comment: Please check fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7fh0x901/3/ Why is it alerting "result"? any idea?

Comment: Seems something of jsfiddle. The window of the result may have the name result.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `x()` function.  It is not needed and causes problems because `this` is reset on every function call in Javascript so the value of `this` inside your `x()` function will either be the `window` object or `undefined` (if in strict mode).

You can use this simplification instead:

```
function a(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;    
    this.show = function() { alert(this.name+" <<show>> "+this.age); }
}

var a1 = new a("rahul", 24);
a1.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Properly built**

```
function a(name, age) {
  this.age  = age;
  this.name = name;
  show: function() { alert(name+' '+age); }
}
```

Comment: through closure concept, shouldn't the function have the value of name

Comment: @jfriend00  I never said that was the answer to begin with.

Comment: @Rafael - you posted it as an answer.  It is not an answer and does not solve anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sure it does it explains why he can't use this inside a function that doesn't have those parameters.

Comment: @Rafael - but the problem with `this` inside of `x` has nothing to do with a lack of arguments to `x`.

Comment: Your new version of the code isn't even proper javascript.